# How to checkout last n-th checked out branch in git?

Tags: git

The story is like this: I worked on branch A, and I checked out branch B. I thought branch A was the master branch, but it was not. So after working on B a bit, I did "git checkout master". The question is: How can I go back to branch A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git checkout @{-2}
```

The `@{-2}` means "the second previous checked out branch".

See `git help rev-parse`. There are many, many different ways to refer to commits.